# UWP Change loading state using binding and async functions

Tags: asynchronous, uwp, uwp-xaml, ui-thread

I am coming from an Angular 2 and a C# back end background, so for the Angular side of things I am used to working with async functions and code, as well the C# background I understand the base libraries.

I am trying to create a simple page that has a a button, and a loading gif. You click the button the loading gif appears, 10 seconds later it disappears.

I can make the loading start no problem, but the nature of the async code jumps the execution and instantly makes the gif disappear.

How do I go about starting the spinner / making a gif visible, waiting 10 seconds in a non ui-blocking manner, and then finish with a thread-safe way of ending the animation / gif visibility?

View-Model code:

```
public class LoadingViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Visibility _loadingState;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public LoadingViewModel()
        {
            this._loadingState = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public Visibility LoadingState
        {
            get {
                return this._loadingState;
            }
            set {
                this._loadingState = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

MainView.xaml.cs:

```
public LoadingViewModel LoadingViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.LoadingViewModel = new LoadingViewModel();
        }


        private async Task BeginLoading()
        {
            LoadingViewModel.LoadingState = Visibility.Visible;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            }).ContinueWith(EndLoadingState);


        }

        //Updated and works but is there a better way?
        private async Task BeginLoading()
        {
            LoadingViewModel.LoadingState = Visibility.Visible;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                await EndLoadingState(); //<-- New EndLoadingState doesn't accept parms
            });


        }

        private async void EndLoadingState(object state)
        {
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                LoadingViewModel.LoadingState = Visibility.Collapsed;
            });
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await BeginLoading();
        }
```

And lastly a basic stack panel with my button and image:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,144,0,144">
            <Button Content="Begin Loading for 10 seconds" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Height="157" Width="366" FontSize="22" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#FF58FF00" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Margin="0,25,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Assets/LoadingBubbles.gif" Visibility="{x:Bind Path=LoadingViewModel.LoadingState, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes sorry I am reading right now I am at work and had to move on from this problem for a short time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try using a `bool` property in your `LoadingViewModel` instead of `Visibility` as the latter is a UI attribute. You generally don't want that in your *ViewModel*. If your target version of Windows 10 is *14393* or higher, you can bind it directly without a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`. And the binding doesn't need to be `TwoWay` also.

```
 Visibility="{x:Bind Path=LoadingViewModel.IsLoading, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Second, XAML binding will actually take care of dispatching the updated value onto the UI thread. So you can also get rid of `Dispatcher.RunAsync` and have a normal `void` method

```
private void EndLoadingState(object state)
{
    LoadingViewModel.IsLoading = false;
}
```

Finally, your `BeginLoading` method(best to rename it to `BeginLoadingAsync`) can be simplified to

```
private async Task BeginLoadingAsync()
{
    LoadingViewModel.IsLoading = true;

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    EndLoadingState();
}
```

Hope this helps!